# How to run a query when multiple values are set

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search data from database when 2 values are set. i.e I want to search  dentists of a specific city (i.e NewYork).

The problem is, the query shows the results of second value only (i.e it gives all the dentists available in database).

```
if (strlen($searched_city, $searched_speciality)>0) {
    $searched_speciality = $_POST['search-by-speciality'];
    $searched_city = $_POST['search-by-city'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE City_ID LIKE '$searched_city' 
                                    AND Speciality LIKE '$searched_speciality'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

        echo '
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>No recod Found</h2>
            </div>
        ';
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '$row[1];'
    }
```

The query works fine if I run it to search both values separately.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This looks perfect for me. `City_ID` are you sure it's not City name?

Comment: `strlen($searched_city, $searched_speciality)` works? You also are open to SQL injections. You also probably want an `else` after the `mysqli_num_rows` conditional.

Comment: It is ID of the city. not the name. The problem is, query works if i run it in phpmyAdmin. But it doesn't work properly when i put it in php script. The problem is with isset, as i think.

Comment: Yes, you need to check the string length of each variable. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php Also id/name doesn't matter, a malicious user can bypass that, unless your code is casting the data to an integer (it isnt).

Comment: @chris85 it works fine when i search doctors by city, or doctors by speciality. 
When I put them together, (to allow mysql query to check both conditions simultaniously and show data according to thse two conditions) they won't work for God knows what reason. Neither it displays an error message.

Comment: This is the same code for just one search? Are `$searched_city` and `$searched_speciality` defined before the conditional, if so why define them again?

Comment: Don't put `$row[1]` in quotes. Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: as side note it is very bad practice to inject `$you-vars` into query like this. you SHOULD use prepared statements and when you will it's much more likely you will not come over such issues! Read:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
and https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic nothing. Query shows the same results it shows for single search (i.e for the specialities only, and ignores the $searched_city variable.).
No error message is displayed.

Comment: Well, are you sure that is not the expected result? Maybe that is the actual situation, ie. all rows that match the first condition also matched the other condition too?